# The given code is returning me an empty JSON output

Tags: java, android, json, api, url

```
void url_get(double lati,double longi) {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location="+lati+","+longi+"&radius=1000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                TextView json = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.json3);
                String theString = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
                json.setText(theString);
                //System.out.println(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

        }
```

The code was working fine when I had hardcoded the latitude and longitude values.However when I tried to pass the values of latitutde and longitude through the function,It dint get recognized.I suppose the URL wasnt built properly.Could you please suggest a way to build my url with the values of latitude and longitude?

Comment: What did you hardcode the lat and long as ? Can you provide a sample ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the values to string using:

```
Double.toString(double);
```

or:

```
String.valueOf(double);
```

So your string should be something like this:

```
url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location="+String.valueOf(lati)+","+String.valueOf(longi)+"&radius=1000&types=hospital&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY");
```

#### Note

In your code a `"` is missing at the end of the string.

Comment: Stupid me! Thanks a lot :)